# MaterializeCSS dropdown with Ionic not working

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework, material-design, materialize

I'm developing an Ionic mobile app with Materialize CSS. The problem is when I have to add components like dropdown menu.

```
 <!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
  <a class='dropdown-button btn' href='#' data-activates='dropdown1'>Drop Me!</a>

  <!-- Dropdown Structure -->
  <ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content'>
    <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
  </ul>
```

The problem is href in dropdown-button, which redirect to a Route which address # instead of showing the menu.

How can I make working this component?

Thanks

Comment: I didn't tried it but mayby you can change <a class to a <span class= ... and remove href

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work anyway..

Comment: and to button ?? on doc specifies any button : Add a dropdown list to any button. Make sure that the data-activates attribute matches the id in the <ul> tag. http://materializecss.com/dropdown.html

Comment: Please post your solution as new answer, with your example!

Comment: Did you find solution for this? For me, it is even displaying the dropdown1 contents.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is late to answer this question, but wanted to share somethings...

I think the dropdown problem is with the jQuery, because it is not supported by cordova or phonegap hybrid application, where you have used the ionic.

You can use pure javascript or angularjs in hybrid applications. you can also use ionic's dropdown and add a custom class using materializecss's dropdown design by copying the dropdown class from materialize.css file.

Best way to use materializecss in ionic frame work is to use the CSS code only, and use other javascript plugins to get that effects.

You can also use ionic material if you like some of it's features similar to materializecss